# Is this IntelliJ inspection warning a false positive?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, static-analysis

I'm looking at ProducerPerformance.java from https://github.com/apache/kafka.

Looking at [this part of the file](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/tools/ProducerPerformance.java#L114):

```
        byte[] payload = null;
        Random random = new Random(0);
        if (recordSize != null) {
            payload = new byte[recordSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < payload.length; ++i)
                payload[i] = (byte) (random.nextInt(26) + 65);
        }
```

There is an inspection saying that "Condition `i < payload.length` is always false."

I don't see how it could always be false. `recordSize` is an `Integer` coming from a command-line parameter. Is there something I'm not seeing here?

Comment: No, looks pretty much like a false positive. The code analysis may treat recordSize as always null thus thinking that the if may never be true.

Comment: This only makes sense if `recordSize` could only be `null` or `0` before this chunk of code. How is `recordSize` actually set?

Comment: @JoachimSauer `Integer recordSize = res.getInt("recordSize");` with `Namespace res = parser.parseArgs(args);`. See https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/tools/ProducerPerformance.java#L57

Comment: In that case I agree with maio290: seems like a bug in the analysis.

Comment: Similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829958/intellij-idea-hint-condition-is-always-false-can-that-be-true-here-java

Comment: Please tell if the issue is reproduced for you with the latest version? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/

Comment: @OlgaKlisho this has been fixed in 2021.1. Thanks.

Comment: @BasilBourque good idea, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning happened with IntelliJ IDEA 2020.*. The latest version, 2021.1, fixes this issue.

Comment: Can you link to the Issue page for more info?

Comment: @BasilBourque I will see if I can find it. I said the latest version fixes the issue because I no longer get this warning with the new version (and I've checked that the warning is not suppressed).